# Using netem on traffic filtered by iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, tc

I would like to use netem for only partion of the traffic on bridge.

### Edit 1

So, I was able to figure out at least something.

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0.1 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0.1 root handle 1: prio
tc qdisc add dev eth0.1 parent 1:3 handle 30: netem delay 500ms
```

Hovewer, I'm not able to make a fwmark filter on this. If I try to `-j MARK --set-mark 6`, I'm unable to filter it using `tc filter`:

```
tc filter add dev eth0.1 parent 1:0 u32 match mark 0x0006 0x0006 flowid 1:3
```

When I enter filter directly into `tc filter`, packets are being delayed (proof that that filtering works). When I use -j DROP in iptables, the packets are being dropped (proof that iptables is matching the packets).

But still, I'm not able to combine it.

Comment: Are you aware that netem is working on egress (output) only (workarounds exist)? Hoping this can be done with iptables alone (ie: without ebtables), your iptables rule must match outgoing packets

Comment: Hello. The problem is not in iptables rule or in netem. The problem is matching packets in iptables to be processed by netem. iptables as such works (I can drop packets without problem) and also netem works OK (I can delay all passing packets). So, the only thing I want to solve is marking packet in iptables and delaying that marked packet.

Comment: all you said is true. that doesn't change what I said. Please add your (complete) iptables rules in the question.

Comment: Okay, your question was on the right place. I came to it few minutes ago, flushed all iptables (I wanted to test it simple) and ... then I realized I'm marking packets matched by physdev-in and trying to delay them by qdisc - thus on output. Why I'm always making so stupid mistakes? :)

Comment: Should I make an answer or should I just delete this?

Comment: It's possible to work around the feature limitation for incoming by using an ifb interface. So if you're fine with outgoing only, either answer yourself or delete it. If you really need to filter on incoming, somebody can try an answer (which is a bit more complex), perhaps me. It would then still help if you added your iptables rules, for ease of reproduction.

Comment: Hi, there was only one rule in FORWARD chain: `-m physdev --physdev-in eth0.1 -m statistic --mode nth --nth 3 --packet 0 -j MARK --set-mark 6` marking every third packet going into eth0-vlan1. 
As I only need to alter traffic passing through the bridge, I don't need to alter/reschedule ingress (all packets are going through some port out and INPUT is intentionally unwanted.